# Multiplatform Angular4 Project. Subdomain as Platform Name

Tags: angular

I want to build a Multiplatform Project with Angular4. For Example i use a Movie Website.

We got a domain named: movie.com

Now we want to make a couple of websites like:

```
the-pate.movie.com
sin-city.movie.com
batman.movie.com
etc...
```

All Websites looks from the Structure exactly same, just the Colors will change. So we need to load different Style Files. (Any ideas how to solve this in cleanest way? Please tell me when you guys got any idea.)

And we work with a Rest API Server. So we need to get on each platform, the correct articles. So we need to bind a platform ID on each platform.

How we do this? We Write a Service? a Guard? Ore both ways are wrong? My Programming Skills are not so high. So please try to explain it easy.

Best Regards!

Comment: probably the best would be to handle it in your build process. but with the lack of information you can't expect a decent answer.

Comment: It happend again... I search after some weeks with google, and just find my unsolved own topic :P